# Why doesn't the compiler allow the returned generic from the peek method to not be optional?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

While implementing a rendition of a stack data collection in a Playground, I noticed that the compiler does not allow the generic returned from the peek method to not be an optional.  Why is this?  Are generics optional by default?

```
public struct Stack<T> {
    private var elements = [T]()
    public init() {}

    public mutating func pop() -> T? {
        return self.elements.popLast()
    }


    public mutating func push(element: T){
        self.elements.append(element)
    }


    public func peek() -> T {
        return self.elements.last
    }


    public func isEmpty() -> Bool {
        return self.elements.isEmpty
    }


    public var count: Int {
        return self.elements.count
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that `self.elements.last` returns an optional `T?` and that does not match your return type `T`. Just change it to  `public func peek() -> T?`

Comment: You're right, the error does show a red line below the last method in which I didn't notice.

Comment: *"the compiler does not allow the generic returned from the peek method to not be an optional"* : The compiler allows it. **You** defined the return type as non-optional. – *"Are generics optional by default?"*: That question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elements` is an array of type `T`. The `last` property is optional since it returns `nil` when an array (or a collection in general) is empty. So, `self.elements.last` is optional by design: `T?`.

But your `peek()` function expects `T` as a return value:

```
public func peek() -> T {
    return self.elements.last
}
```

All you have to do is change the return value of peek into `T?` since peeking into an empty `Stack` should be `nil`.

As to "*Are generics optional by default?*":

`T`could be any type you could think of, it is generic after all. For example you could choose **`T`** to be **`Int?`**:

```
let s = Stack<Int?>()
let last = s.peek()
type(of: last)        //Optional<Optional<Int>>.Type
```

In this case, `last` is an **`Int??`** which none other than **`T?`**